# stored procedure declaration error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am new with stored procedure.

I am taking value of column in one variable and checking it with If block.

**My code for this is as follows:**

```
  create proc billRet 
as 
BEGIN
DECLARE @amt float
set @amt=select amount from bill where Id='2425'
If (@amt>1100.50 )
Begin
select @amt
print 'Amount greater '+@amt;
END
Else
Begin
select @amt
print 'Amount Smaller'+@amt
END
END
Go
```

Its showing me error on print statement and declaration of @amt variable.

please tell me Where i am making mistake.

Please help me.

Comment: Please include the complete error messages you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type comes after the variable name:

```
DECLARE @amt float;
```

You have to manually convert to strings and concatenate to get printing to work:

```
print 'Amount greater ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),@amt);
```

(If you don't do the `CONVERT` or a `CAST`, then SQL Server will attempt to convert the string to a [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and add the two together)

Also probably want:

```
select @amt=amount from bill where Id='2425'
```

Comment: Again pasted new code , giving error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure billRet, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: @Freelancer - please stop editing your question, such that the answers no longer make sense - I tried rolling it back but that was only partially successful. I've added another possible fix that's required. If you want to show your code as it now is, please add that as a separate code example at the bottom of the question, and clearly marked as "this is where the answers so far have gotten me" or similar.

Comment: really sorry. Will remember from next time. Problem is been solved by your answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SET @amt = (select amount from bill where Id='2425')
```

and this,

```
print 'Amount greater ' + CAST(@amt AS VARCHAR(50));
```

Comment: Again pasted new code , giving error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure billRet, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.